# WordPress custom menu delimiter/separator

Tags: wordpress

Is there a simple way to create a customer menu in WordPress that does not output a list? Basically I want a menu with pipes between the links. Every solution I've found says to style them with a right border or background image, but I'm not crazy about this solution and what if I wanted something like a "/" or "»" between each link? I think live type would look better too. I already know I can remove the container div and ul tags using "items_wrap" and "container". Any ideas on how to ditch the li's too and add separators? A filter or hook?

I'm looking to do this with WordPress functionality. I know I can resort to CSS and jQuery if needed and in fact am doing that, but I'm still curious as to how to override the menu system.

Answer (score 1):

Just style the list propperly

```
li { list-style-type:none; }
li:before { content:"/ "; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sVvs8/

Comment: This has pretty poor support. I think I'd use jQuery to add the delimiters before using this CSS.

Comment: You might consider adding that to your question.